# Qt: Creating button on QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt

I have QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView. I'm adding QGraphicsRectItem to scene and I've encounter some difficulties...

I want to create button on my Item. I've tried to create QPushButton but when I used show() method it appears in new window. I've also tried do another QGraphicsRectItem that could be button, but I don't know how to place it in my QGraphicsRectItem that is placed on scene.

Comment: Hi, I think you have better chances with QGraphicsWidget.. look here. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-basicgraphicslayouts-example.html

Comment: Sounds great, I'll check this solution and give feedback how is going.

Comment: It helped me a lot, Thanks!